# Not getting data back from php into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am working on a project that uses JavaScript (AJax) to call a php file to query a MySQL Server. I have traced the call to php and see that it is working but the AJax call never gets anything.  below is my JavaScript and PHP code, could someone look at it and tell me what I am missing.

javaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#members').on('input', function() {
        var opt = $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]');
        /*getMember(opt.length ? opt.attr('id'): 0);*/
        $.ajax({
            url: 'data/members.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'action':'get', 'status':opt.attr('id')},
            sucess: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("We have a problem");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

php:

```
$action = $_POST["action"];

if ($action == "get") {
    $memberID = $_POST["status"];
    try {
        require "../../classes/data.php";
        $data = new data();
        $conn = $data->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberID = " . $memberID;
        $result = $data->query($sql);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $returnData = $row;
        }
        echo $returnData;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to echo an associative array? Need to look at `json_encode` for starters.

Comment: Is your browser's console indicating any errors?

Comment: Tried it with json_encode and without, both not working.

Comment: check your permissions on your php file.  Chmod 777 and then try your code.

Comment: Development server is a Windows 10 machine not Linux.

Comment: Oh, well this is the correct behavior then : ).  Sorry, couldn't help myself.

Comment: What does your browser's console indicate?  Any errors appear there?  Add console.log(opt.attr('id')) after your var opt statement and see what appears in your console when the code executes.

Comment: Have you looked at the server logs to see if your php is failing? Do you have any tools in the browser installed to see the communication between the browser and the server? What debugging have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error:

Replace:

```
url: 'data/members.php';
```

for this:

```
url: 'data/members.php',
```

',' at the end

Comment: Just caught that, just a typo it is right on the code running on the server still not working.

Answer (score 0):

PHP part

```
// You have SQL injection here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE memberID = " . $memberID; 
$result = $data->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // You probably want this as array 
    $returnData = $row;
}
// use json_encode
echo json_encode($returnData);
```

JS part:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data/members.php',
    type: 'POST',
    // add data type here
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {'action':'get', 'status':opt.attr('id')},
    sucess: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Boris, when I use NetBeans XDebug I and follow the php code line for line, the data being sent from AJax is correct (an array of 2 value->key pairs) and then I step through the sql code to query the database everything is working right.  $returnData turns into any array with one records (which is what I am looking for).  I have tried to add the json_encode and no matter what happens the ajax success never fires.  I have tried using alert the get the results and I have tried populating the form the data is for.

Comment: '#members' is select box? try with '$('#members').on('change', function() {' and you can get current value by of select box with '$(this).val()' instead of '$('#members').on('input', function() {', if this is not working you will need to post more code

Answer (score 0):

As soon and I learn to spell life will be good....had a typo in the javascript...had success as sucess, no wonder it never fired.  Now one more question data is being return a array:array how do I access the data? If I use data["key"] I get nothing. If I alert data I get all of the data returned from mysql.

```
$(function() {
$('#members').on('input', function() {
    var opt = $('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]');
    /*getMember(opt.length ? opt.attr('id'): 0);*/
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/members.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'action':'get', 'status':opt.attr('id')},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("We have a problem");
        }
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Does the data gets the record as array. As boris pointed out

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // You probably want this as array 
    $returnData = $row;
}
```

$returnData always gets the last row as it over writen.

you need to code it like.

```
$returnData = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // You probably want this as array 
        array_push($returnData,$row);
    }
```

And when the result is returned to javascript u need to use JSON.parse

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'data/members.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'action':'get', 'status':opt.attr('id')},
        success: function(data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("We have a problem");
        }
    });
```